# How to optionally update field if parameters not None

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have a table with non nullable columns:

```
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def surname = column[String]("surname")
}
```

I want update some columns only (if not `None`):

```
  def update(id: String, name: Option[String], surname: Option[String]) = {
    (name, surname) match {
      case (Some(n), Some(s)) => byId(id)
        .map(l => (l.name, l.surname))
        .update((n, s))
      case (None, Some(s)) => byId(id)
        .map(l => (l.surname))
        .update(s)
      case (Some(n),None) => byId(id)
        .map(l => (l.name))
        .update(n)
    }
  }
```

Is there more elegant way to do this? What if there are lot of update parameters?

Comment: I was curious of this as well. I see, only 2 ways of achieving this. The first one, without hand-written SQL: fetch all fields that are optionally modified, use `getOrElse` to figure their values, pass it into `.update`, do it all within a single transaction. The second one: write an SQL by hand where on each `Option` you append `column=value` to the `UPDATE` statement. The former, let you do everything using Slick but with an overhead of fetching data from the DB, the other requires handwritten SQL but has no overhead. I see no other option, but I'd like to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am able to make two queries, I am left with the option to use the existing one and always make only one update:

```
  def byId(id: String) = ???

  def update(id: String, name: Option[String], surname: Option[String]) = {
    val filterById = byId(id).map(u => (u.name, u.surname))
    for {
      (existingName, existingSurname) <- filterById.result.head
      rowsAffected <- filterById.update((name.getOrElse(existingName), surname.getOrElse(existingSurname)))
    } yield rowsAffected
  }
```

**PD**: Same for large objects .. we map the entire row and then make a kind of patch to update it again